# Can i have a Custom Action which is a link to another page

Tags: custom-actions

Can i have a custom action which is simply a link to another website? I don't want any modals or anything.  Just a simple link which takes me to another page.

Comment: This is SharePoint 2013. The custom action should be added via app

Comment: check this one http://www.abelsolutions.com/totm/creating-a-custom-action-in-2-steps-with-sharepoint-designer/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a custom actions via SharePoint app (SharePoint hosted also). Here is nice tutorial in MSDN https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj163954.aspx

To redirect a page you need to specify UrlAction where you can use some SharePoint tokens, like {ListId}, etc. If you need some more logic you should specify a `Command` for you custom action.
Also you have to specify WHERE do you want to add this custom action and register it appropriately.

If you need more informaction about how to create custom actions check link below:

1. http://www.sharepoint-journey.com/custom-actions-in-sharepoint-2013.html
2. http://www.sharepointnutsandbolts.com/2010/01/customizing-ribbon-part-1-creating-tabs.html